# R subset returns limited set with warning

Tags: r, subset

I have a data.frame with 12500 obs. of 8 variables, one of which is State (taxes$State). I want to subset the data down to multiple states that I get from user input in Shiny, but I kept getting dropped data when I added more than one state. I've got down to the subset function that is acting funky. I get no warning with just two states, but the third throws the exception. In every case, I'm limited to 250 obs. on the return. For example

```
temp<-subset(taxes, State==c("AL","MO",TX))
```

Warning message:1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
2: In `==.default`(State, c("AL", "MO", "TX")) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

I've tried other variables also with the same result

```
temp<-subset(taxes,StateFullName==c("Iowa","Missouri","Texas"))
```

Warning message:
In StateFullName == c("Iowa", "Missouri", "Texas") :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length

Any ideas as to why I'm limited to 250 obs?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just need `%in%` to compare a `vector` of `length` > 1 i.e.

```
subset(taxes, State %in% c('AL', 'MO', 'TX'))
#   State amount
#4     MO  14143
#27    TX  11517
#30    AL  14465
```

Or using `data.table`, we convert the 'data.frame' to 'data.table' (`setDT(taxes`), set the `key` column as 'State' and extract the rows that have 'MO', 'TX', 'AL' in the 'State'.

```
library(data.table)
setDT(taxes, key='State')[c('MO', 'TX', 'AL')]
#    State amount
#1:    MO  14143
#2:    TX  11517
#3:    AL  14465
```

---

To understand why your code didn't work, let's check the logical vector output.

```
with(taxes, State==c('AL', 'MO', 'TX'))
# [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [13] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [25] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [37] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
# [49] FALSE FALSE
```

> Warning messages: 1: In is.na(e1) | is.na(e2) :   longer object length
>   is not a multiple of shorter object length

None of the elements were `TRUE` for this example.  The way it compares is based on the recycling.  The first 3 elements of 'State' is compared with the vector 'AL', 'MO', and 'TX' in that order

```
 taxes$State[1:3] == c('AL', 'MO', 'TX')
 #[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Here, we compare element-by-element between corresponding values of both the vectors and as

```
  taxes$State[1:3]
  #[1] AK AL AR
```

is not matching the 'AL', 'MO', and 'TX' at the corresponding positions, it returns 'FALSE'.

The same way, it is compared up to the `length` of 'State' column, i.e. the next comparison is

```
 taxes$State[4:6] == c('AL', 'MO', 'TX')
 #[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Here also all are `FALSE` as the corresponding 'State' elements were 'AZ', 'CA', and 'CO'.  We get a warning at the end because

```
 nrow(taxes)
 #[1] 50
```

`50%%3!=0`

If the `nrow` of the dataset is `51`, the warning will not be there, but still as comparison is based on position, we may not the result as intended.

#### data

```
set.seed(24)
taxes <- data.frame(State=sample(state.abb), 
       amount=sample(400:20000, 50, replace=TRUE), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Answer (score 1):

The logical expression in the function is not according to what you want. It is looking for an observation that is equal to the vector `c("AL","MO","TX")`. As 12500 is a multiple of 2, `subset` tries subsetting considering both elements in the vector. As 12500 is not a multiple of 3, it can't use the same process when the vector has three elements, and throws the warning.

In short, an option to substitute the logical expression would be:

```
temp <- subset(taxes, State == "AL" | State == "MO" | State == "TX"))
```

This can be tested in this simple example:

```
df <- data.frame(x = c("A", "B", "A", "C", "D", "E", "A", "C"))
subset(df, x=="A" | x =="B" | x == "C")
```

Answer (score 0):

Yep. So what I didn't know or understand since I've never used a vector for subset was that subset sees c(a,b,c) as a sequence not a list for individual matches. Thanks all for the help!